# Stored checkbox values not checked when trying to edit them

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, gsp

In the main page,I click on the below checkboxes to store the values in a **arraylist 'Method'**.
After saving, When i try to edit the main page, how to display the respective checkboxes 'checked' at that time.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Method" value="icon" /> <g:message code="icon.label"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Method" value="touch-icon" /> <g:message code="touch.label"/>
```

Comment: I'm directly sending the values where as in the other case value="${publicRuleInstance?.status }" is happening. I want to pull the values from arraylist and compare with the respective checkbox to check them.

Comment: How are you saving and getting the information? You need to get the values first, then make whichever checkbox needs it the attribute of `checked=checked`

Answer (score 0):

Well, after you saved the data, in order for you to check these checkboxes based on your data, you have to send this data back to the view right? So you send the data back to the gsp and you might wanna do a verification using `<g:if>`. If the the data is valid, you use a checkbox with the 'checked' attribute, otherwise `<g:else>`, you put an empty checkbox.

If you are saving this data by doing and AJAX call, after you saved the data, you can return '200' to the client and update the checkboxes on the ajax callback.

Hope this helps! :)